# How to solve the differential equation :$e^{6t}y''+\frac{2}{9}y=e^{3t}?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would you solve this?

$$
e^{6 t} y^{\prime \prime}(t)+\frac{2}{9} y(t)=e^{3 t}
$$

It has no recognizable standard form, so how to proceed?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha does give a solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+the+differential+equation+(e%5E(6t))y%27%27+%2B+(2%2F9)y+%3D+e%5E(3t)), but as one might expect it's absolutely nasty. I wouldn't know how to derive it, and it's not really a closed form solution either. So I've got nothing here, really.

Answer (score 2):

Using $y(t)=u(e^{-3t})$ one gets $y'(t)=-3e^{-3t}u'(e^{-3t})$, $y''(t)=9e^{-6t}u''(e^{-3t})+9e^{-3t}u'(e^{-3t})$ so that the differential equation reads now as
$$
e^{6t}y''(t)+\frac29y(t)=9u''(e^{-3t})+9e^{3t}u'(e^{-3t})+\frac29u(e^{-3t})
$$
Now replacing $s=e^{-3t}$ gives
$$
9u''(s)+\frac{9}su'(s)+\frac29u(s)=\frac1s
$$
which is in the territory of Bessel equations.

Comment: Can we proceed without the Bessel thing? Because we did not learn the Bessel equations but still it is required from us to solve it

Comment: You can do a power series expansion of $u$, the Frobenius method. You could also to that for $y$ in the original equation, but the power series product that you get somewhere will make the result a bit more complicated.